# Bypassing mobile detectability from the browser

Tags: browser

First of all, I know that there is a "request desktop site" in the Android browser, but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have this [site](http://www.dazn.com) and they have an Android app as well. Because of that, they want users to play videos from their app and not from the Android browser. But "for reasons", I want to play it on the browser. Defining user agents as `chrome/windows` didn't help either.

Do you guys have any idea how to do it?

Comment: How did you change the use agent in Chrome mobile?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so a file named `chrome-command-line` needs to be put in `/data/local/chrome-command-line`.

Download that onto your PC and then use

```
adb push chrome-command-line /data/local/chrome-command-line
```

If you get `couldn't create file: Permission denied`, run `adb root` and then `adb push chrome-command-line /data/local/chrome-command-line`.

Proof:

> [image]

---

You can download the `chrome-command-line` file or you can make your own. First, make a file that contains: `chrome --user-agent="<stuff>"`. The stuff is here: https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/

Example: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36`

Comment: It still doesn't play videos from the site. It no longer asks you to play from the app. The site opens but doesn't play the video on mobile device. Can it be detecting the screen size and disabling the playback?